# Zend framework installation

Tags: zend-framework

After including the library in php.ini, I try to create a project in a DOS window by typing `C:\wamp\www\Zend\bin>zf.bat` create project quick start I got a error message:

> '"php.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

What causes this error message to occur, and what is the solution?

Answer (score 4):

```
•   Go to ‘My Computer’ > Properties > Advanced Tab >EnvironmentVariables.  
        Environment Variables box will open, View SYSTEM VARIABLES, scroll the list to      ’ PATH ‘ > 
double click ’ PATH ‘ . Add the following line to the end of the PATH  C:\xampp\php
Zend Framework

•   Extract the Zend Framework files to C:\wamp\php\zf.
•   Edit the php.ini file. You will find it at C:\wamp\php\php.ini. 
 Find the line that says ’ include_path ’ and edit the line: 
 Windows: “\path1;\path2″
 include_path = “C:\wamp\php\zf\library”
 •  Open a shell and cd to C:\wamp\www folder and type this:
 C:\wamp\www>C:\xampp\php\ZendFramework\bin\zf.bat create project      
  testproject(project name)


•   Now Copy the Zend Folder from your ZendFramework folder ( C:\xampp\php\zf/library /Zend) into the library folder of your new test project ( C:\xampp\htdocs\testproject\library\Zend
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your `php.exe` is in your path variable.

Answer (score 0):

as said before:

> Make sure that your php.exe is in your
>   path variable.

Or edit that bat file to use absolute path to the php.exe on your system,
**and make sure you have php.exe in your system.**

Besides, PHP should be developed as part of a LAMP stack and not Wamp in cases of big projects (otherwise, why use ZF?)